# How to stop spacebar from triggering click effect on a button?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, actionlistener, keylistener

I have created a jframe and i have added a button which, after it get clicked, it asks u to press any button, which also displays on the button.
(its displays should go like this -> "Click Me" -> "Press Any Button" -> "Space Bar")
My problem no.1 is that, i dont want to go from "Click Me" to "Press Any Button" by pressing the spacebar.
And my problem no.2 is that, when i am at "Press Any Button" and i press spacebar, on release, it goes back to "Press Any Button" instead of staying at "Space Bar".
Here is my code.

```
    public class Test {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

static class starton implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button;
    private JFrame frame;

    public starton(JButton button, JFrame frame) {
        this.button = button;
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText("Press A Button");
        button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
        button.addKeyListener(
        new KeyListener() {
            @Override 
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                String text = null;

                    char a = e.getKeyChar();
                    text = ""+a+"";
                    if (a == ' '){
                        text = "Space Bar";
                    }

                button.setText(""+text+"");
                button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
                button.removeKeyListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            }
        });
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    double height = screenSize.getHeight();
    int frame1w = 600;
    int frame1h = 400;

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Foo");
    frame1.setSize(frame1w, frame1h);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    frame1.setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me");
        button1.setSize(button1.getPreferredSize());
        button1.addActionListener(new starton(button1, frame1));
            // add more code here
        contentPane.add(button1);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The `JButton` installs a series of key bindings to control user input

You can inspect what these are using something like...

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
InputMap im = btn.getInputMap();
for (KeyStroke ik : im.allKeys()) {
    System.out.println(ik + " = " + im.get(ik));
}
```

On my system, it prints

```
pressed SPACE = pressed
released SPACE = released
```

This tells me that the <kbd>Space</kbd> key is bound to the action keys `pressed` and `released`

In order to disable these keys, you need to provide your own binding...

```
Action blankAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
};

ActionMap am = btn.getActionMap();
am.put("pressed", blankAction);
am.put("released", blankAction);
```

This just replaces the `pressed` and `released` bindings with a empty `Action` which does nothing.

Now, a word of warning - key bindings can be different on different platforms/look and feels; You should also beware that users often have a pre-defined expectation of what certain controls can and can't do, changing them will affect how they react to you program

As to your second problem, the `button` is still using the same `ActionListener` you originally registered, so whenever you press <kbd>Space</kbd>, it's triggering the `ActionListener` again, and adding a new `KeyListener` which is going to compound your problems

You either want to use a separate `ActionListener` for both buttons or you want to remove the `ActionListener` from the button when it's first triggered - I'd go for the second, it's easier to understand the code

> no, i mean, if i disable the "press" for spacebar, would i be able to press it when i am at "Press Any Button"?

The simplest solution would be to use two different buttons, one with an `ActionListener` which set up the other button, which had a `KeyListener` attached to it.

If, for some reason you "really" don't want to do that, then you need to remove the `ActionListener` from the button when it's first triggered

```
static class starton implements ActionListener {

    //...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText("Press A Button");
        button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
        button.addKeyListener(...);
        button.removeActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: about the first1, why i want to disable the "pressed" for spacebar? isnt this supposed to be the whole point? i mean to press the spacebar? also i dont have multiplue buttons, it is just 1 .. also on the second problem, i tried removing with success the action listener but i want to be able to do the routine as many times as i want to, not just once

Comment: It took your entire question as *"How to stop spacebar from triggering click effect on a button?*" and *" i dont want to go from "Click Me" to "Press Any Button" by pressing the spacebar."* as meaning, you wanted to disable the [Space] bar functionality for the button. *" also i dont have multiplue buttons, it is just 1 "* - Yes, and that's you "core" problem;

Comment: *" i tried removing with success the action listener but i want to be able to do the routine as many times as i want to, not just once"* And? Again, two buttons would help solve much of issues you are having.  You could simply swap them in place as you needed to. Because you have both a `KeyListener` AND an `ActionListener` registered against the button, each time you press [Space], they will BOTH be triggered, to my mind, you're just asking for trouble which be easier solved by using two (or more) buttons, each with their own targeted functionality

Comment: also what are thoses am.put?

Comment: Look up `ActionMap`

Comment: no, i mean, if i disable the "press" for spacebar, would i be able to press it when i am at "Press Any Button"?

Comment: Okay, again, the best solution is to use two buttons, separate the logic and functionality. If you "really" don't want to do that, then you need to remove the reference to the `ActionListener` when the `actionPerformed` method is first called, this will prevent it from been triggered again in the future, but, frankly, this is a hack and makes your code more difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes about due to your nested control of the `KeyListener` within the action listener. Since <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> is the default keyboard button for the equivalent of clicking the button, every time you hit <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> `actionPerformed` method of the buttons `ActionListener` is fired. You can see this happening if you get the `actionCommand` of the `ActionEvent` fired and printing it. You could also use this to control what code gets performed. Like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println("Button Action: " + e.getActionCommand());
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Click Me"))
    {
        //Your existing code but remove this line
        //button.removeKeyListener(this);
    }
}
```